# Is it possible to reorder methods by invocation in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In "Clean Code" book by Robert C. Martin there is great tip to sort methods according to their invocation, like this:

```
void e() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
}

void a() { /*implementation*/ }

void b() {
    d();
}

void d() { /*implementation*/ }

void c() { /*implementation*/ }
```

This has big advantages:

- *"A class should be readable like a newspaper (...)"*: you can read the class top-down without approaching a method that you
  don't know where is used
- *"(..) starting with the most important methods"*: high level methods are on the top, so you
  stop reading the class at point where you understand what it does and
  don't need to go into lower level of detail

**Is there any plugin or other way to sort like this automatically**? Because once I write bigger class it's time consuming to do reordering manually, not speaking of code updates.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not suggest to do so.

Why? Assume your code looks at the beginning like the one from your question.

```
void e() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
}

void a() { /*implementation*/ }

void b() {
    d();
}

void d() { /*implementation*/ }

void c() { /*implementation*/ }
```

Now a small code change is done and `a()` also calls `d()`. Then following your example the code would now look like

```
void e() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
}

void a() {
    d();
}

void d() { /*implementation*/ }

void b() {
    d();
}

void c() { /*implementation*/ }
```

Which would lead to following changes a reviewer of your code would have to check.

```
@@ -4,12 +4,14 @@ void e() {
     c();
 }

-void a() { /*implementation*/ }
-
-void b() {
+void a() {
     d();
 }

 void d() { /*implementation*/ }

-void c() { /*implementation*/ }
+void b() {
+    d();
+}
+
+void c() { /*implementation*/ }
```

So he has to review additional changes, which are actually no code change.

Comment: yes, sticking any practice comes with some overhead. But this shouldn't stop us from applying it - there are benefits also. Classes that are easier to read are worth doing it. The benefits come with time saved on reading and understanding - Bob writes in his book that reading and understanding takes more time than actually typing.  Otherwise I would fear moving a method to place where it logically fits better because the reviewer has a change to review that doesn't introduce any change in a way the program works.

Comment: @kiedysktos Agree `reading and understanding takes more time than actually typing`. If your review tool can filter out moven lines your are fine and my answer does not impact you. If it doesn't filter them out then it takes more time to filter them out yourself. As you need to check if the whole method was moved without any change or if it was moved with an additional change. So at the end you would loose the time on the review process.

Comment: thanks, I see your point and appreciate input. However I think it's worth the effort, especially considering the fact I strive for perfection in my classes